# In mgcv::gam(), what is the difference between s(x, by=cat) and s(x, cat, bs='fs')?

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

In this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330346/mgcv-how-to-specify-interaction-between-smooth-and-factor#comment74330932_43330540) about smooth-factor interactions, Gavin Simpson wrote:

> s(x1, by = cat) doesn't create a "fs" class smooth

I understand that

```
y ~ s(x, by = cat) + cat             (a)
//cat is an unordered factor
```

creates a separate smooth for each level of the factor as shown in `summary()` and `plot()` with a confidence interval around each smooth (and that this model doesn't say anything about whether the smooths for those levels are different).

On the other hand, in

```
y ~ s(x, cat, bs = 'fs')             (b)
```

the `summary` shows *one* smooth, but the `plot()` shows *two* smooths and with no confidence intervals.

So my questions are:

1. How should the `fs` smooth in (b) `summary()` be interpreted? Does the p-value say anything about whether the smooths for `cat` levels are different?
2. Why does `plot()` in (b) shows two curves without confidence intervals?
3. What is the exact difference between (a) and (b)? When should I use one instead of the other? And how does their interpretation differ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

#### Q3

The `by` smooth variant has a separate smoothness parameter for each level of `cat`. In one sense you can think of these smooths as creating entirely separate smooth functions (they're aren't quite, they share the same basis for example), hence you have `nlevels(cat)` entries in the `summary()` output.

`fs` smooths share a single smoothness parameter, and in that sense are a bit closer to the smooth equivalent of random slopes; all the smooths are being pulled towards 0 (null function), with the smooths for some levels of `cat` pulled more towards 0 than others.

#### Q1

You should just treat the `fs` smooth summary as some measure of overall importance of the set of smooth functions. If the `fs` smooth is the only one in the model where `x` is a covariate then you could say interpret this as a test of the amount of variation in the response that can be explained by smooth functions of `x`, against a null of no effect. It's like an omnibus test in the sense that it is over the set of smooths.

Put another way, it is a bit like a test for a variance term of random slopes in a mixed effects model; this would be on a single variance parameter and you get a single test over the entire "effect" even though it represents $m$ slopes.

#### Q2

Typically, one would use `fs` where there where `nlevels(cat)` was large and you aren't particularly interested in the specific levels, just like you might work with random effects in a mixed effects model.

As there could feasibly be a separate line for the many levels of the factor but we think of this as a single "smooth" you get a single plot with each smooth superimposed to get some idea of the variation within and between individual functions. It would get very messy it if also showed confidence bands for each smooth.

In the `by` case, because you conditioned on the observed set of levels (sensu fixed effects in a mixed model) it makes sense to view these are being of individual interest, hence a separate plot per level of `cat`.

Also note that this is just the default plot to get a quick look at the fitted functions.

Comment: Many thanks, @Gavin! For **Q1**, you wrote `It's [fs] like an omnibus test in the sense that it is over the set of smooths`, I guess this means: p-value of `fs` is not about whether there is an actual interaction between `x` and `cat` (i.e., it doesn't say anything about whether the smooths for the factor levels are different in shape) (*please correct me - I'm not a statistician*). I tried exactly model `(b)` (note: no separate `s(x)`) on a dummy data where `y` depends on `x` but not on `cat`, and `cat` doesn't modify effect of `x`: the result was `fs` having a very low p-value.

Comment: Here is the code for model `(2)` that I've tried:
`x  = rnorm(1000, 1, .2);
y  = rnorm(1000, 1, .1) * x^3 * rnorm(1000, 1, .1) + x^-1;
cat = rep(factor(c(1,2)), 500);
plot(x, y, col = cat);
m = mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, cat, bs = 'fs'), method = 'REML');
summary(m)`

Comment: It seems if I want to compare `x` effect between `cat` levels, the model should be `s(x) + s(x, by = cat) + cat` where `cat` is an ordered factor. (?)

Comment: Yes, that's right; it's not a test of different shape, rather a test of a null hypothesis where all the smooths are flat and all the random intercepts are zero. Re your model (2) example, that's expected because `x` has an effect so the test says the data provide evidence against a zero effect & zero random intercept everywhere null hypothesis. You can do the ordered `by` but that only compares to a reference level (in your case with two levels that's not an issue) and it can depend on how well you can estimate the reference smooth; flip the order of levels & estimates can change

Comment: You can use an ordinary factor `by` variable smooth for this too https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/ but it requires post processing. You could do this with the `fs` smooth also but you have to handle the random intercept bit of this basis

Comment: What is the difference between "y ~ s(x, by = cat) + cat"   and "y ~ s(x, by = cat)"?

Comment: @derelict The former includes the parametric factor term which models (when combined with the constant term) each group's mean response. The latter has smooth centred about the mean of the response variable measured over all groups, which will be problematic because the shapes of the smooths now also needs to try to model each group's mean as well as how the response changes with `x`, which will compromise the estimation of the smooth effects